# in python, i want to run app Scheduler one time in a minute but i run 2 time in a minute how can i solve it in

Tags: python, flask

in python, i want to run app Scheduler one time in a minute but i run 2 time in a minute how can i solve it in

```
def say_hello():
    print("hi")

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=say_hello, trigger="interval", minutes=1)
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this example helps you? task 1 will run every 60 sec and task 2 will run every 30 sec.

```
import sched
import time

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def print_event(name):
    print('EVENT:', time.time(), name) 

print('START:', time.time()) 
scheduler.enter(60, 1, print_event, ('first',))
scheduler.enter(30, 1, print_event, ('second',))

scheduler.run()
```

Comment: no Sir i need this to run the function after every one minute

Comment: whats the difference between 1 minute or 60 seconds??